# If I have an android app that needs to be improved, and I need to make the same app on iOS, which tools should I use?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, xamarin, frameworks

There is an Android app for:

- marking certain events
- answering a few questions related to the event
- reporting the mark and the answers to an institution

A database is already created and I have access to the code of everything created. My job is to:

1) Upgrade the app with some small additional features, like reviewing sent messages and a direct call button to the institution

2) Make the same app for iOS mobile devices.

Is it better to continue working with the Android Studio and make the iOS app separately, or to use a framework for both operating systems, like Xamarin?

I am a novice programmer and I do not have any experience with C# or Swift. The relevant limitations are time (3 months) and complexity of developing. The tools should be free too.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use react native for the same.Its also open source

Comment: If you develop the iOS app separately it will probably take some more time but afterwards changes/maintaining the app will be less complex/expensive.

Answer (score -1):

> Cross Platform (`Not Recommended`)

`Xamarin` , `Phonegap` , `Ionic`

I Don't Suggest you to use `Cross Platform` Because of Output Size is Unreasonable And ... (Google it!)

> Native
>   As my experience Better way is using Native platform, your app can use last libraries and has more stability than apps build by hybrid or cross platform tools. Also Better performance

Comment: Xamarin apps are native, do not have an unreasonable output size and  they have the same performance because they are native.

Comment: I've used Xamarin for some time now and haven't seen any of these issues. Xamarin is essentially native and I've never seen any unreasonable size APK's/IPA's?